# docker's VOLUME isn't mounting host files

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have this docker file:

```
FROM node:0.10.38
VOLUME /opt/build
WORKDIR /opt/build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD node app.js
```

However, when I got to run the container, I get the error that app.js does not exist, specifically `/opt/build/app.js` does not exist.  I've also tried `ADD` and `COPY` to do this, both say it can't find anything, and I'd like to use VOLUME so it writes to the host's log that is also in /opt/build. All desired files are in fact on the host as well. By the way, I'm using coreos as the host OS.

Comment: What command are you using to run the container? Host volumes are only mounted if you use the `--volume` (`-v`) option to `docker run` (and specify a `<host path>:<container path>` mapping).

Comment: Even when using a custom docker file I need -v? `docker run -name build_instance -p 80:8080 -i -t build_img` is what I'm using.  I also tried `docker run -v /opt/build -name build_instance -p 80:8080 -i -t build_img` and that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you need `-v`. Otherwise, this creates a shared data volume, but _doesn't_ mount it to the host.

Comment: (Think about it -- if the VOLUME command were intended to be used for mounting host directories, it would take two arguments, not one -- the host directory, and the guest directory).

Comment: Yeah, thanks that worked, any chance of writing that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#volume --

The `VOLUME` Dockerfile command is equivalent to `-v /opt/build` ("Adding a data volume"), not equivalent to `-v /opt/build:/opt/build` ("Mount a Host Directory as a Data Volume"); the latter is what you want here.